# Split a dataframe into multiple to run a function that only takes two-column dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, dplyr, purrr

I want to perform a column-wise operation in R on column pairs. **The function I actually want to use is not the one shown here, because it would complicate this example.**

I have a dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(p1 = c(-5, -4, 2, 0, -2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 7)
                 ,p2 = c(0, 1, 2, 0, -2, 1, 3, 3, 2, 0))
```

and a vector of the same length as the `df`:

```
tocompare <- c(0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 4, 16, 12, 6, 9)
```

I want to run a function that compares each column of `df` to the `tocompare` object. The steps I need to take is:

1. Make a two-element list. First element is a two-column dataframe `x`, in which the first column comes from the `df` and the second column is the `tocompare` object. Second element is a number. (this is needed for my actual function to work, I appreciate that it is not needed in this example). This number is constant for all iterations of this process (it's a number of rows in `df` / length of `tocompare`) in this example, it's `10`.

```
data1 <- list(x = cbind(df %>% select(1), tocompare), N = length(tocompare))

# select(1) is used rather than df[,1] ensures the column header is kept
```

2. Compare the two columns of the first element (called `x`) of the `data1` list. The function that I use in real life is not `cor`; this simplified example captures the problem. I wrote `my_function` in such a way that it needs the `data1` object created above.

```
my_function <- function(data1){
x <- data1[[1]]
cr <- cor(x[,1], x[,2])
header <- colnames(x)[1]
print(c(header, cr))
}

cr_df1 <- my_function(data1)
```

I can do the same for the second `df` column:

```
data2 <- list(x = cbind(df %>% select(2), tocompare), N = length(tocompare))
cr_df2 <- my_function(data2)
```

And make a dataframe of final results:

```
final_df <- rbind(cr_df1, cr_df2) %>% 
`rownames<-`(NULL) %>% 
`colnames<-`(c("p", "R")) %>% 
as.data.frame()
```

the output will look like this:

```
> final_df 
   p         R
1 p1 0.7261224
2 p2 0.6233169
```

I would like to do this on a dataframe with thousands of columns. The bit I don't know is *how to split the single dataframe into multiple two-column dataframes and then run `my_function` on these many small dataframes to return a single output*. I think I would be able to do it with a `loop` and with transposing the `df`, but maybe there is a better way (I feel I should try to use `map` here)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than looping you can use `map` to iteratively apply your function. To split up your dataframe into columns, just select each column one at a time. `1:ncol(df)` will generate a sequence of the column numbers. So

```
library(tidyverse)
map(1:ncol(df), function(column_number) df %>% select(all_of(column_number)))
#> [[1]]
#>    p1
#> 1  -5
#> 2  -4
#> 3   2
#> 4   0
#> 5  -2
#> 6   1
#> 7   3
#> 8   4
#> 9   2
#> 10  7
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>    p2
#> 1   0
#> 2   1
#> 3   2
#> 4   0
#> 5  -2
#> 6   1
#> 7   3
#> 8   3
#> 9   2
#> 10  0
```

To get your function to process these columns, first alter it to output dataframes

```
my_function2 <- function(data1){
x <- data1[[1]]
cr <- cor(x[,1], x[,2])
header <- colnames(x)[1]
tibble(header = header, cr = cr)
}
```

Then wrap it all up with `map` but use `map_df` so that each iteration gets bound as a row to a dataframe

```
compare_fn <- function(df, compare_list, my_function){
    map_df(1:ncol(df),
           function(column_number) my_function(list(x = cbind(df %>% select(all_of(column_number)), compare_list),
                N = length(tocompare))))
}
```

And run it with

```
compare_fn(df, tocompare, my_function2)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>   header    cr
#>   <chr>  <dbl>
#> 1 p1     0.726
#> 2 p2     0.623
```

EDIT: If the function within the `map_df` call is taking too long and you want to parallelize it with `furrr` you can alter it with

```
library(furrr)
plan(multisession, workers = 10) # or however many threads you have available

compare_fn2 <- function(df, compare_list, my_function){
    future_map(1:ncol(df),
           function(column_number) my_function(list(x = cbind(df %>% select(all_of(column_number)), compare_list),
                N = length(tocompare))))
}

#Since future_map() returns a list instead of a dataframe
#add bind_rows() to group each element into a dataframe

compare_fn2(df, tocompare, my_function2) %>% bind_rows
```

Comment: Thank you. This does exactly what I want! However, it's also incredibly slow (~1.5min per row, and it seems it's mostly down to `map_df` - I've got 11000 rows). I was thinking to use the `future_map` from the `furrr` package, but it has not yet implemented `map_df` (but they did implement `map`). Is ther a way to use `map` and then append the result to a dataframe? (So, I guess, similarly to a loop)

Comment: @Wera, I've updated my answer with `furrr`

Comment: As an aside, I doubt it's `map_df` that's taking that long, but instead the function you're calling within `map_df` (whatever replaces `cor` in your real-world use). However, `furrr` will help there too. You should also look at trying to optimize the code within the `my_function2 ` call.

Answer (score 0):

A more generic way to do it is to use `split.default()`,

```
lapply(split.default(df, seq(ncol(df))), function(i) cbind(i, tocompare))

$`1`
   p1 tocompare
1  -5         0
2  -4         0
3   2         2
4   0         0
5  -2         2
6   1         4
7   3        16
8   4        12
9   2         6
10  7         9

$`2`
   p2 tocompare
1   0         0
2   1         0
3   2         2
4   0         0
5  -2         2
6   1         4
7   3        16
8   3        12
9   2         6
10  0         9
```

Then apply your function to each element of the list

Comment: HI Sotos, thanks for your reply. Yes, I could use `apply` with `cor`. In fact I would not even need apply. But I am not actually using `cor` (as explained in the text), but a more complicated function that takes two-column dataframes, and therefore I haven't come up with a way to use apply. I need a solution that will produce many lists of two-column dataframes, just as explained in the question.

Comment: I edited but again I m not sure what you need here

Comment: thank you, I didn't know about `split.default` I think this brings me closer to what I need to do.